# the operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, Operator. error, idk what's wrong

Tags: java, parsing, boolean

so i am making a presentation about parse tree and i do copy paste the code that you will see, but it baffles me that it got an error on the if condition, it says that "the operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, Operator"(can you tell me why this happen btw i'm kinda new), and i do checked the code and frankly i do not know where it went wrong. as far as i checked all of it return a number which should be fine but i do get the error.

this the code that has the error  :

```
if (OperatorList != null && OperatorList.get(OperatorList.size()))
```

this is the full code of the main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParseTree tree;
        String problem = "3+5*16/2^2-6";
        ArrayList<Operator> OperatorList = new ArrayList<Operator>();
        ArrayList<Node> NodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        
        //takes the problem and converts every character into
        //an operator and then places them in the operator list
        for (int i = 0; i < problem.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("success.");
            switch(problem.charAt(i)) {
            case '+':
                OperatorList.add(new Plus());
                break;
            case '-':
                OperatorList.add(new Minus());
                break;
            case '*':
                OperatorList.add(new Multiply());
                break;
            case '/':
                OperatorList.add(new Divide());
                break;
            case '^':
                OperatorList.add(new Power());
                break;
            default:
                //checks if the integer has two digits and combines it into one operator
                if (OperatorList != null && OperatorList.get(OperatorList.size())) {
                    int num = OperatorList.remove(i-1).Operate();
                    num *= 10;
                    OperatorList.add(new Integer((int) problem.charAt(i) + num));
                } else {
                    OperatorList.add(new Integer((int) problem.charAt(i)));
                }
            }
        }
        
        //places each operator into their own node and
        //puts it into a node list
        for (int i = 0; i < OperatorList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(OperatorList.get(i));
            NodeList.add(new Node(OperatorList.get(i)));
        }

    }

}
```

would you mind telling me why it gives the error? i see nothing returning anything but a number except for the node page which has this code (i am assumming the problem comes from here, but i do not know for sure), here is the code :

```
public class Node {
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Node parent;
    private Operator content;
    
    public Node(Operator op) {
        this.content = op;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        parent = null;
    }
    
    public Node() {
        this(null);
    }
    
    public void setLeft(Node n) {
        this.left = n;
    }
    
    public void setRight(Node n) {
        this.right = n;
    }
    
    public void setParent(Node n) {
        this.parent = n;
    }
    
    public void setOperator(Operator op) {
        this.content = op;
    }
    
    public Node getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }
    
    public Node getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }
    
    public Node getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
    
    public Operator getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
    
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.content.getOrder();
    }
}
```

am sorry for my english, and thank you for your help

here is the link where i copy the code incase you need it:
https://github.com/McJet/ParseTree

Comment: `OperatorList.get(OperatorList.size())` does not return a boolean. What did you want to check?

Comment: What are you trying to test about the Operator? An Operator isn't a boolean. (Also, `OperatorList.get(OperatorList.size())` would result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

Comment: It is Java not C, unlike in C where params of ``if`` can be integer and in java it has to be a boolean . In java we can ``&&`` only on boolean.  Hence try to use ``if(OperatorList != null && !OperatorList.isEmpty())``

Comment: Also, you don't need to check `OperatorList != null`: you assign it once, giving it a non-null value. You may as well just remove that.

Comment: If you are copying code for an assignment rather than writing the code yourself, you should at least try to find good code to copy. A definite clue that you have not find good code is if it fails to compile. There must be thousands of attempted arithmetic parsers on GitHub; sadly most of them are badly-written or completely broken. You will learn a lot more by writing your own code, even if it turns out to not be any better than the other student efforts you find on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your if-statement doesn't return a boolean. When you use `OperatorList.get(OperatorList.size())` it returns an Operator object. If-statements can't evaluate non-boolean values. Remember, if-statements checks if a statement is true. It's like asking if the integer 5 is true or not. The error essentially means, that you are comparing a boolean value to an Operator object, which is not possible. Also `list.get(list.size())` will give an exception, as `list.size()` will always be 1 more than the last index. Instead you should write `list.get(list.size()-1)`

Comment: You might also care to mention the fact that `list.get(list.size())` would give an exception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with

```
if(OperatorList != null && !OperatorList.isEmpty())
```

It is pretty basic stuff, try to run through java basics again

Comment: `OperatorList` is never null so why check it?

Comment: In this case yes. no need to check for null also.. In general, we normally check for null and then isEmpty. Similar to CollectionUtils.isEmpty of apache library